# Date.getTime() gives two different values for same timestamp

Tags: javascript, date

I have two variables. weekStartDate and startDate. they both hold essentially the same timestamp:

```
this.startDate  Date {Mon Mar 26 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)}
this.weekStartDate   Date {Mon Mar 26 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)}
```

the problem is: when I try to getTime(), they show a slightly different value:

```
this.startDate.getTime()    1332700200000
this.weekStartDate.getTime()    1332700200506
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: User `this.weekStartDate.setMilliseconds(0)`.

Comment: Can you show how you're instantiating them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is 506 milliseconds. The number of milliseconds isn’t displayed when you call `toString()` on a `Date` object, so anything more precise than seconds will go unnoticed unless you compare the numeric value.

To reset the milliseconds to `0`, use:

```
this.weekStartDate.setMilliseconds(0);
```

Comment: yes. why? when the two timestamps are exactly the same? why is there a difference?

Comment: @amit They are not exactly the same — the problem is that you only see the difference in the numerical timestamp representation.

Comment: They aren't exactly the same. weekStartDate was based on the current date and time, correct? The milliseconds on that date object were never reset, so a difference of 506 milliseconds shows up.

Comment: @JoelLundberg Yeah, that’s what I said, wasn’t it?

Comment: @Mathias Bynens I forgot to direct the comment at amit, and you posted your comment while I was writing mine. So yeah, that's what you said.

Answer (score 2):

I think the milliseconds are different. Set the milliseconds of boths dates to zero then the dates will be the same:

```
this.weekStartDate.setMilliseconds(0);
this.startDate.setMilliseconds(0);
```

edit: damn i was to slow